# keep returning 'numpy.float64' object is not callable when running GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am running a block of codes using GridSearchCV to compare the best parameters used in LinearSVC.
However, I kept running into the same

```
TypeError 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

even if I converted all my inputs into float64 format. Anyone can help?

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

clf = LinearSVC()

parameters = {'random_state':[0, 1, 42], 'tol':[1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3]}

scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score(y_val.values.ravel().astype('float64'), 
                     y_pred.astype('float64'), beta=0.5))

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring=scorer)

grid_fit = grid_obj.fit(X_train.values.astype('float64'), 
                        y_train.values.ravel().astype('float64'))
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace. Also, for the next time, please do spend a minute to see how to properly format your code (done it for you this time).

Comment: ---> 18 grid_fit = grid_obj.fit(X_train.values.astype('float64'), y_train.values.ravel().astype('float64'))

Comment: For the next time (again) , please notice 1) such info should be in the question itself, not in the comments 2) code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (since never executed), and should **not** be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that the issue was caused by my 'make_scorer' function. It should be written as 'make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=0.5)'

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting your y_train_values to float ? I assume you are doing a classification since you use SVC. The target values should be integers.

Comment: So my targets values are either 0 or 1 and their natural data type is already int64.

Comment: Here is how I extracted my target values from the original dataframe: targets = flight_data[flight_data['flight_delay_targets'].notnull()==True][['flight_delay_targets']].values

Comment: Here are how I split my train and test datasets: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, targets, test_size = 0.2, random_state=0)

Comment: I discovered that such TypeError might not be caused by the model since I tried different models such as decision tree and still ran into the exact same error. Perhaps the way I extracted my target values was problematic?